# Can Team Foundation Server 2010 be used to version small projects and one off files that don't necessarily require a full TFS project structure?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Going forward, our group will be developing .NET apps using TFS, and the application lifecycle management will be great.

We also have a lot of legacy java apps that we currently version by zipping them up and throwing them in source safe. Or an other example would be a couple of stored procedures used for a report or scheduled job, we want them versioned and backed up with the rest of our source.

Can we achieve that same sort of one off functionality using TFS? We'd like all of our source in one place, but some of it just needs to be very simple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

TFS is made to handle your scenario- not just to manage your SDLC and .NET applications.

For example, we store our legacy SPs and documentation in TFS. You can have those files versioned with your development branch too if you so desire.  Essentially anything you can do with the code for your .NET application in terms of versioning you can achieve with all of your legacy files as well.

So you can feel confident, moving forward, that your choice to move to TFS is the right one if that is your only outstanding concern.

**How to Add Files**

Go to Source Control Explorer (View -> Other Windows -> Source Control Explorer or Double Click in Team Explorer View).

Navigate to where you want to store your legacy files in the structure or if you need to create a new folder to store the files (Icon is on the left of the toolbar).

Once the folder is created, click the icon with a little plus beside it to the right of the new folder icon to "Add Items to Folders."  You can also right-click in the window to the right-hand side that shows you the files in the folder and both create new folders and add files to the folder.

[image]

Inside of this dialogue you can select your legacy files and add them to TFS.

Comment: That's great! Do you have any resources to show me how? I don't see an intuitive way to create a new folder in source control and drop zip files into it. Thanks!

Comment: I can walk you through it- I will add an example to my answer for you and look around for a similar explanation on the web.

Comment: So it all has to be done with Visual Studio, or I'm assuming Team Explorer, for non-developers?

Comment: So, when select my top level and my second level (Repository, Projects), the New Folder button is grayed out. I guess that's why I was confused. Are there specific permissions that need to be set?

Comment: You can also do it via the portal site for your application or yes to use Team Explorer.

Comment: Contributors and above can create folders - if the user is just part of the Readers group they will not be able to though.

Comment: @NgM let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1922/discussion-between-ironicmuffin-and-ngm)